# Windows PostgreSQL Unicode ODBC driver commection string CommLog not working

Tags: postgresql, odbc

CommLog set to 1 in connection string BUT no log file being written anywhere.

What am I missing here?

I wonder how does the driver figure out the log file path to write to? Am I supposed to tweak the system wide ODBC settings to make this work?

```
ODBC;DSN=overload;DATABASE=overload;SERVER=192.168.34.18;PORT=5432;CA=r;A6=;A7=100;A8=4096;B0=255;B1=8190;BI=0;C2=dd_;CX=1c502bb;A1=7.4;UID=pavel@access;PWD=********;CommLog=1
```

Comment: show the connection string itself?..

Comment: Perhaps the process does not have write permissions in that directory. Check with Process Monitor (for Windows) or `strace`/`truss` on other OS.